# Rabbitmq server fail to start

Tags: linux, ip, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have install two rabbitmq-server in two computer A and B.
But I can't start rabbitmq-server in computer A. 
rabbitmq-server can be started in computer B.

Error message in computer A looks like:
*{error_logger,{{2012,11,20},{19,55,37}},"Protocol: ~p: register error: ~p~n",["inet_tcp",{{badmatch,{error,epmd_close}}*

epmd server refuse the connection!!!

Computer A try to connect its own epmd server with global ip address like 172.16.217.128
Computer B connect its own epmd server with local ip address which is 127.0.0.1

epmd only allow local ip address's connection request. So computer A are refuse to connect.

BTW, I do a few more test.
If I run "ping 127.0.0.1" command in computer A:
*20:03:59.571514 IP 172.16.217.128 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 9299, seq 2, length 64
20:03:59.571533 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 9299, seq 2, length 64*

If I run "ping 127.0.0.1" command in computer B:
*19:44:03.612930 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 1805, seq 11, length 64
19:44:03.612941 IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 1805, seq 11, length 64*

Computer A use source ip address 172.16.217.128 when he ping himself!!!
That's the reason why Computer A can't start rabbitmq-server, epmd refuse ip address 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output of `/bin/hostname`, and ensure that string appears in /etc/hosts on the "172.16.217.128" line. Then kill epmd if running, and restart rabbitmq. You should find it works normally once it can rendezvous with epmd (on port 4369).

BTW, I wouldn't quite call 172.16.217.128 a "global" IP, as it is an rfc1918 IP.